# Как написать такой скрипт, чтобы при наборе 0 очков грузилась другая сцена?

Tags: c#

В моем проекте используется Text Mesh PRO Gui. Задача: Написать скрипт, который даст понять игре, что когда значение очков в TMPPro = 0, то начнется загрузка другой сцены, например "MainMenu".

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Unity? WPF? WinForm? Можно уточнить, если вы хотите сделать это на WinForms:
new MainMenu.Show();
yourForm.Hide();

MainMenu должен быть Form